# Promise.all([..]).then never resolves

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a number of individual Promises that look like this:

```
var performancePerMonth = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var path = some_path;
  getFromApi(path);
});
```

They all use this method called getFromApi() to perform a request:

```
function getFromApi(path, callback) {

  request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: base_uri + path,
    headers: { 'TOKEN': 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN' }
  },

  function (error, response, body) {
    console.log('Status:', response.statusCode);
    console.log('Headers:', JSON.stringify(response.headers));
    console.log('Response:', body);
    return body;
});
```

Because I need to run the requests together and get an array including all results, I added all individual Promises into a Promise.all:

```
exports.perform = function(req, response) {
  Promise.all([performancePerMonth, performancePerPlayer,..]).then(function(results) {
    console.log('Then: ', results);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log('ERROR Promise.all');
    console.log('Catch: ', err);
  })
};
```

The problem is, although the requests are performed fine as I can see from the logs on getFromApi() method, the array of results is never returned. The method runs but apparently never gets to the function inside `.then` and this:

```
console.log('Then: ', results);
```

is never reached (neither the catch function under it).

Seems as if the program runs only until all requests are performed and forgets to return results.

Comment: Your functions don't return the promises nor solve them

Comment: In your first code block, nothing ever calls `resolve()` so that promise never resolves.  You have to hook up your async functions to actually call `resolve()` when they finish.  Promises don't contain any magical powers to know when async operations are done - you have to tell them by calling `resolve()` or `reject()`.

Answer (score 1):

You're never resolving the promise.

```
var performancePerMonth = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var path = some_path;
  getFromApi(path, resolve);
});
```

Your `getFromApi` function also has a callback but it never gets run. You probably want `callback(body);` instead of `return body;`

Comment: Oh, whoops, didn't see that. Editing answer.

Comment: `getFromApi()` does not call the callback it is passed so this won't work by itself either.

Answer (score 0):

`function getFromApi(path, callback)` accepts a callback argument so lets use that as the callback for `request` instead of the anonymous function you have

```
function getFromApi(path, callback) {
  request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: base_uri + path,
    headers: { 'TOKEN': 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN' }
  }, callback);
}
```

Now lets use that anonymous function, slightly modified to call resolve/reject as required, in `performancePerMonth` etc

```
var performancePerMonth = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var path = some_path;
    getFromApi(path, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            reject(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Status:', response.statusCode);
            console.log('Headers:', JSON.stringify(response.headers));
            console.log('Response:', body);
            resolve(body);
        }
    });
});
```

You may want to check `response.statusCode` is one that indicates a successful request before blindly resolving the body too - many request API's don't consider a non 2xx status returned in the response as an error

so, you may need something like

```
var performancePerMonth = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var path = some_path;
    getFromApi(path, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            reject(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Status:', response.statusCode);
            console.log('Headers:', JSON.stringify(response.headers));
            console.log('Response:', body);
            if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300) {
                resolve(body);
            } else {
                reject(response.statusCode);
            }
        }
    });
});
```